# is it possible use telegram APIs in an ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, chat, telegram, chatbot

can it possible use `telegram` APIs in ionic app?
i've just tried an instant really chat but i would use telegram for using bots for example.
if it is possible can someone help me?
thank's

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? do you want to route your messages via telegram API or are you building an interface to Telegram Bots?

Comment: i would to route messages with telegram API or simply make a bot

Comment: use the Telegram bot api then

Answer (score 1):

**CORE API**.

Yes, you can easily use Ionic here, in fact the official web client is built on Angular itself! You can look at the source code [here](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram) and there are several Core API libraries for JS such as telegram.link

**BOT API**

Yes, but you will be limited to a few functionalities. Basically your Ionic app will just be a mirror of the bot. In order to receive the message, you will have to cleverly extract the message sent to the bot and pass it to your Ionic framework, which isn't very hard. There is one [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xyz.pwrtelegram.messenger) using a boosted bot API. There are several Web Apps and Progressive Apps using the bot API and even a java applet!